# Google ColabにおけるPhantomJSの使い方

Tags: python, web-scraping, phantomjs

Google Colabでスクレイピングの練習をしているのですが、以下のコードを動かしても以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。どのようにPATHを指定すればこの問題は解決するのでしょうか?
コードは https://review-of-my-life.blogspot.com/2017/10/python-web-scraping-data-collection-analysis.html にあったものを参照しています。

```
!pip install selenium
```

```
#trendAnalytics.py
from selenium import webdriver  
from pandas import * 
import time

#Access to page
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

エラー

```
usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    708                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 709                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    710         except:

/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1343                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
-> 1344                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1345                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'phantomjs': 'phantomjs'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3131533f6b12> in <module>()
      4 
      5 #Access to page
----> 6 browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
      7 # DO NOT FORGET to set path
      8 url = "http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/text?safe=on&q=Python&users=50"

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, desired_capabilities, service_args, service_log_path)
     54             service_args=service_args,
     55             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 56         self.service.start()
     57 
     58         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
---> 83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     84                 )
     85             elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:

WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: 参考： 英語版での類似質問(とその回答) - [PhantomJS with Selenium error: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37903536/2322778)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 注意

警告にも出力されている通り、PhantomJS は既に更新が停止している古いツールです。Headless Chrome など新しいツールの使用を検討してください。

参考: [SeleniumからStableになったHeadless Chrome/Firefoxを使ってみる](https://qiita.com/orangain/items/6a166a65f5546df72a9d) -- Qiita (2018/05/06)

### 解決法

現在のままだと PhantomJS のバイナリがインストールされていないのと、その PATH が指定されていないのでエラーが出ています。それぞれを解決するように以下のようなスクリプトにするとエラーは出なくなります。

```
# PhantomJS をダウンロード
!wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
!tar xf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

# Selenium をインストール
!pip install selenium

# executable_path を指定した上で WebDriver を用意
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/content/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs")
```

- [実際に動く Google Colab の例](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/119JMayqFzKBdYN4spcFvv5AkfJTKXoFg)
- [Python 版 PhantomJS WebDriver のドキュメント](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver)

Comment: パスの問題解決しました!ありがとうございます!