# スクレイプ結果の出力

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

[以前に回答していただいた点](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50914/phantomjs%E3%81%A7%E5%8F%8E%E9%9B%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AEcsv%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E6%A0%BC%E7%B4%8D)を修正して以下の様なコードを実行したのですが、欲しい出力が何も表示されずにプログラムが終了してしまいます...。何か原因に心あたりのある方がいらっしゃれば回答いただけると助かります。

```
#https://review-of-my-life.blogspot.com/2017/10/python-web-scraping-data-collection-analysis.htmlの練習
#trendAnalytics.py
from selenium import webdriver  
from pandas import * 
import time

#Access to page
# PATH を指定した上で WebDriver を用意
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/content/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs") #PhantomJSのサポートは終わっているらしい...?Headless Chromeを使うべきなのか...?
#https://qiita.com/orangain/items/db4594113c04e8801aadを下のセルで試す。
# DO NOT FORGET to set path
url = "http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/text?safe=on&q=Python&users=50"
browser.get(url)
#!touch trend.csv
#df = pandas.read_csv('trend.csv') #エラーの要因
df = pandas.DataFrame()　#前回の回答の反映
#Insert title,date,bookmarks into CSV file

page = 1 #This number shows the number of current page later

while True: #continue until getting the last page
  if len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".pager-next")) > 0:
    print("######################page: {} ########################".format(page))
    print("Starting to get posts...")
    posts = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".search-result")#何かを取得している...。

    for post in posts:
      title = post.find_element_by_css_selector("h3").text
      date = post.find_element_by_css_selector(".created").text
      bookmarks = post.find_element_by_css_selector(".users span").text
      se = pandas.Series([title, date, bookmarks],['title','date','bookmarks'])
      df = df.append(se, ignore_index=True)
      print(df)

    #after getting all posts in a page, click pager next and then get next all posts again
    btn = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a.pager-next").get_attribute("href")#次に投稿を取得するページのurlっぽい。
    print("next url:{}".format(btn))
    browser.get(btn)#次のページへ移動
    page+=1
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)#sleep()みたいなものか...?
    print("Moving to next page......")
    time.sleep(10)#これ要る...?

  else: #if no (next) pager exist, stop.
    print("no pager exist anymore")
    break
#while文終わり

df.to_csv("trend1.csv")
print("DONE")
```

出力

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
no pager exist anymore
DONE
```

Comment: `no pager exist anymore` は出力されているようですので、 `while True`直下のif文の条件である`len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".pager-next")) > 0` が Falseになっているようです。セレクタは正しいですか？

Comment: すいません...確認してみます...。

Answer (score 1):

次のページへ遷移するために CSS セレクタを使って次のページのリンクを取得しているのですが、参考になさっているブログ記事が書かれたときとはページの構造が変わっており、そのままのセレクタでは動作しなくなっています。

このため、`browser.find_elements_by_css_selector` を使っている 2 箇所を修正しないと上手く動作しません。ブラウザの「検証」機能等を使ってスクレイピング元のサイトを解析し、新しいセレクタに更新してください。

なお、デバッグ時に何回もスクレイピングする際にはその間の時間を充分に長くとって、サーバーに負荷をかけないようにご注意ください。

Comment: 了解です。毎度回答をいただき本当にありがたいです。

Answer (score 1):

アクセス先URLの`http://b.hatena.ne.jp/search/text?safe=on&q=Python&users=50`をブラウザで開いてソースを確認してみてください。
指定したCSSセレクタの`.pager-next`が見つからなければそこで処理を終了するようなプログラムになっているので、**書いた通り**にプログラムが動いているに過ぎません。

ちなみに、`pager-next`で検索すると以下の通りヒットします。

**HTML/CSS (ブラウザの開発者ツールで確認)**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**実際のブラウザ上での表示結果**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 返信に感謝します。ソースを確認します。